# In CI/CD how to manage dependency between frontend and backend?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, portainer

I'll describe my setup to make the problems less abstract, but they don't seem specific to my case.

## Context

We have Python-Django backend and a VueJS frontend, each in a repository, with Gitlab-CI configured and deploy using Portainer (using a stack).
A commit in the production branch of each repository follows this path:

1. commit
2. gitlab-ci pipeline:

   1. build docker image
   2. test image (frontend is tested against deployed backend)
   3. tag image as production:latest
   4. push image back to gitlab registry
   5. webhook the corresponding service (frontend/backend) in portainer to update the deployed image
3. portainer:

   1. pull image
   2. deploy

## Problems

### Deployment synchronization

Imagine we're doing a major change in both frontend and backend, and both will become incompatible with previous versions. So the new versions must be deployed simultaneously.

In our current setup we have to first deploy the backend (what will break the deployed frontend) and then deploy the new frontend, fixing production, but with a "down" period.

### Branch dependency for tests

Sometimes when we develop branch feature-1 in the frontend, it must be tested against branch feature-1 from the backend.

In our current setup all the commits in the frontend are tested against the deployed backend (to avoid replicating the backend in CI, only the production API address is used), resulting in false tests results in such cases.

### Backend integration tests

When a commit is done to the backend, it can break the frontend.

Currently the backend isn't tested against the frontend (only the other way).

## Possible Solutions

For the deployment synchronization problem I thought about creating another repository that would have only one file specifying the versions for frontend and backend that should be deployed. A commit in this repository would result in both Portanier' services webhooks being "curled" for update (backend and frontend). This doesn't guarantee the simultaneous update (one may fail in Portainer and there would be no rollback), but it would be better than current setup.

I'm not sure about what should be used to specify versions here: commit hash, git tag, branch, docker image version... The last maybe avoids having to rebuild and test images, but I think images name and versions are fixed in Portainer' stacks definition, and not easy to update automatically.

For the branch dependency tests I thought about having a file in each repository (frontend and backend) specifying which branch from the backend/frontend to test against. But the CI for each repository would have to replicate the whole deploy environment (running a new backend and frontend to test each frontend commit, for example). This would also allow backend integration tests. Since we're using Docker, that's not very complicated, but will take extra time for each CI pipeline... Also, when the first repository (frontend or backend) is committed, it'll reference a still non existent branch in the other repository, and fail...

These solutions seem awkward to me, specially if these are problems common to CI/CD with Docker. And it can get even uglier when we add more repositories to the mix.

Alternatives?

Thanks for the attention!

(*edit:* for curious, my current setup was based on this [article](https://medium.com/lucjuggery/even-the-smallest-side-project-deserves-its-ci-cd-pipeline-281f80f39fdf))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ### Deployment synchronization
>
> Imagine we're doing a major change in both frontend and backend, and both will become incompatible with previous versions. So the new versions must be deployed simultaneously.
>
> In our current setup we have to first deploy the backend (what will break the deployed frontend) and then deploy the new frontend, fixing production, but with a "down" period.

I'm not a portainer user, but maybe you could rely on some `docker-compose.yml` file or so, gathering both the version of the backend and the frontend? in this case they could be updated at the same time…

Indeed according to [portainer/portainer#1963](https://github.com/portainer/portainer/pull/1963) and [this doc page](https://portainer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/templates.html?highlight=yml#type), portainer seems to support both docker-compose and swarm stacks.

Also, docker swarm provides some features to perform service upgrade without downtime, as documented in [this blog](https://sreeninet.wordpress.com/2017/08/15/docker-features-for-handling-containers-death-and-resurrection/#serviceupgrade), but I don't know to what extent this can be configured in portainer.

> ### Possible Solutions
>
> I'm not sure about what should be used to specify versions here: commit hash, git tag, branch, docker image version... The last maybe avoids having to rebuild and test images, but I think images name and versions are fixed in Portainer' stacks definition, and not easy to update automatically.

While commit hashes are precise identifiers, they are probably not convenient enough to identify incompatible versions. So you may want to rely on [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) using tags (and/or branches) on your Git backend repo.

Then, you may tag the corresponding Docker images accordingly, introducing some synonymous tags if need be. For example, assuming the backend has been released with versions `1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2`, a standard practice consists in tagging the Docker images like this:

- `project/backend:2.0.2` = `project/backend:2.0` = `project/backend:2`
- `project/backend:2.0.1`
- `project/backend:2.0.0`
- `project/backend:1.1.1` = `project/backend:1.1` = `project/backend:1`
- `project/backend:1.1.0`
- `project/backend:1.0.1` = `project/backend:1.0`
- `project/backend:1.0.0`

(removing old images if need be)

> ### Backend integration tests
>
> Currently the backend isn't tested against the frontend (only the other way).

OK but I guess your approach is fairly standard (the frontend depends on the backend, not the other way around).

Anyway, I recall that even if the system under test is a front-end, it may be worth it to implement unit tests (which are less costly to develop and run than integration tests) so that a first stage in the pipeline quickly runs these unit tests, before triggering the necessary integration tests.

> ### Branch dependency for tests
>
> In our current setup all the commits in the frontend are tested against the deployed backend (to avoid replicating the backend in CI, only the production API address is used), resulting in false tests results in such cases.

This may be not flexible enough: in general, CI/CD assumes the integration tests are run using a dedicated backend instance ("dev" server or "pre-prod" server), and if all integration tests and system tests pass, the image is deployed to the "prod" server (and monitored, etc.)

I see from your post that you are using GitLab CI, which has some [native Docker support](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html), so maybe this could be implemented easily.

A couple of hints:

- Assume the backend has been modified in a non-backward compatible version, and the corresponding Docker image is available in a registry (e.g. that of GitLab CI). Then you could just change the specification of that image in the frontend configuration (e.g., replacing `project/backend:1` with `project/backend:2` or so in the GitLab CI conffile).
- Your backend is probably implemented as a REST Web Service, in which case you might also want to add a version prefix in your URL, so that when you switch from `project/backend:1` to `project/backend:2` (with incompatible changes), both versions could be deployed at the same time if need be, to the URLs `https://example.com/api/v1/…` and `https://example.com/api/v2/…`

Also, beyond the solution to have only two repos with CI/CD (backend tested apart, and frontend tested against the relevant version of the backend), the solution you suggested in the first place may also be considered:

> For the deployment synchronization problem I thought about creating another repository that would have only one file specifying the versions for frontend and backend that should be deployed. A commit in this repository would result in both Portanier' services webhooks being "curled" for update (backend and frontend). This doesn't guarantee the simultaneous update (one may fail in Portainer and there would be no rollback), but it would be better than current setup.

You could slightly modify this approach to avoid one such deployment failure: you could add some CI setup to that third repo, that would only contain a `docker-compose.yml` file or so, and move the integration tests from the frontend CI to that "compose" CI…

(FYI this approach is similar to the one suggested in this [DigitalOcean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-continuous-integration-testing-environment-with-docker-and-docker-compose-on-ubuntu-14-04#step-7-%E2%80%94-create-the-testing-environment), where the integration testing is achieved thanks to some `docker-compose.test.yml` file.)

Comment: (1/2)

Thanks for the great reply!

We are already using a compose config to setup our stack in Portainer (AFAIK it uses docker swarm under the hood, so the deploys are already without downtime [when everything goes smooth]). I'm just not sure how easy it's to update the compose config programmatically. But I'll investigate more.
https://github.com/portainer/portainer/issues/1753

Even if the backend doesn't depend on the frontend, I'm afraid we do need backend integration tests to avoid committing to it and deploying a backend that breaks the production frontend.

Comment: (2/2)

At Gitlab-CI, we're already using Docker (dind), but only to build and run the code in that repository (e.g.: the frontend CI only build the image, run and test it for the frontend code).

At last, moving the integration tests together with a "whole system" docker-compose.yml to the third repository seems a nice move!

Comment: @someone How did you end up with this?

Comment: @Hecke29 Never found a simple complete solution. But I'm working in new projects for sometime: smaller teams, no frontend automated tests, both frontend and backend are in the same repository. For my use cases it's working ok.

Comment: BTW @Hecke29, I'm more and more thinking that you (and/or the OP) might be interested in a "monorepo" GitLab CI configuration? see e.g. this other, more recent SO question: [Gitlab CI/CD to Digital Ocean for multiple repos using docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62825637/9164010)

Answer (score 2):

> ### Branch dependency for tests
>
> Sometimes when we develop branch feature-1 in the frontend, it must be >tested against branch feature-1 from the backend.
>
> In our current setup all the commits in the frontend are tested against the deployed backend (to avoid replicating the backend in CI, only the production API address is used), resulting in false tests results in such cases.

and

> ### Backend integration tests
>
> When a commit is done to the backend, it can break the frontend.
>
> Currently the backend isn't tested against the frontend (only the other way).

In my current company, we have Django for frontend(FE) and backend(BE), each in a repository.
we're following trunk-based development. We also use gitlab for CI/CD.
I rolled out what you mentioned here and didn't feel awkward at all.

**Relationship between the environments and this branching model.**

**|Branches|example|environment|**

|master |master| staging|

|release-v*|release-v1.1.10|preprod|

**Tag:**

**|Tag|example|environment|**

|v< MAJOR >.< MINOR >.< PATCH >| v.1.1.10|Production|

Once branches/tags are created or any commit to the defined branches, gitlab will trigger an auto build/deployment.

The frontend has to be tested against the backend. we do that with feature branch.

**feature/< branch-summary >**

developers need to ensure the same feature branch name existing on both FE and BE.

An URL for each frontend/backend is generated for each deployment look like
-fe.< domain >.com for frontend
-be.< domain >.com for backend

eg: there is a feature/mytask in both FE/BE repos. The FE URL is mytask-fe.< domain >.com and BE URL is mytask-be.< domain >.com

You can use docker-compose but in my case, our application is deployed to kubernetes using helm.
A bit further of this implementation, My FE and BE has an k8s ingress which is managed by traefik. The DNS record(for each URL) is automatically created in (by k8s DNS controller), the backend is using DB and Redis which are created every time a feature branch is created or changed. By the convention of feature branch naming, the FE knows how to connect to BE and the BE knows how to use its own DB and Redis.

eg: 
**helm upgrade --install ${RELEASE_NAME} ...**

the RELEASE_NAME is extracted from feature/< branch-summary > ( not exceeding 63 chars)

Other things, you may consider about initialize data for feature branch deployment.
In my case

*)Developers will manage to populate data (maybe running a script as init container in k8s).
If a developer pushes a commit to the same feature branch, this will trigger a re-deployment and all data of DB / Redis will be re-inited. Developer may need to re-populate data and QC may need to restart their testing from beginning of this feature.

*)to avoid creating too many resources in k8s and branches in gitlab repository.
I setup a remove function in gitlab CI in order to delete a feature branch in the BE/FE repository which will trigger a deployment deletion in k8s respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have a further question concerning your answer. When a developer creates a feature branch where there are only front-end modifications, the developer must create a feature branch on the back-end repository even if there are no modifications? It means a build and deployment must be triggered even if there are no modifications to the back-end. Did you implement something to avoid that or you accept this overhead?