# Gitlab CI/CD to Digital Ocean for multiple repos using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci, digital-ocean

Currently I have a project (repo) in Gitlab which is an angular app. I'm using Gitlab CI/CD to build, test, release and deploy. Releasing will build a new docker image pushing it to the Gitlab registry and after deploying it on NGinx in a docker container on my Digital Ocean droplet. This works fine.

Let's say I want to add a backend to it like the MEAN stack so I would have 2 containers running using a docker-compose file.

- container 1 - Angular
- container 2 - Node.js, Express.js and MongoDB

The 2 gitlab projects (repo's) will have to be build separately when a change occurs (own Dockerfile and gitlab-ci.yml file) but deployed together using the docker-compose file.

***Where do I manage/put the docker-compose file?***

I hope my explanation is clear and if I'm assuming correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In CI/CD how to manage dependency between frontend and backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53412038/in-ci-cd-how-to-manage-dependency-between-frontend-and-backend)

Comment: [In CI/CD how to manage dependency between frontend and backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53414567/9164010) is maybe not an exact duplicate question, but the overall idea seems to apply in your use case as well: you could add a `docker-compose.yml` file with dedicated integration tests in a third repository and rely on a tags naming convention to pull the proper backend / frontend versions, **or** maybe just have 2 repos with the `docker-compose.yml` file in the frontend repo. **Otherwise**, follow a so-called *monorepo* setup, that is a single repo with several folders and a single CI.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Monorepos have some great advantages especially in this case but I don't think Gitlab CI is possible with a monorepo that's why I assumed to create 2 repos. This is my first project using Gitlab CI/CD. I'll try to look further.

Comment: If you start with GitLab CI, I'd first recommend bookmarking the `.gitlab-ci.yml` YAML reference manual (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/). Next, GitLab CI indeed supports monorepo workflows, cf. [this doc page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/workflows/monorepo.html) which gives an example of use of the `changes:` key; see also e.g. [this article](https://medium.com/swlh/on-monorepos-and-the-deployment-with-gitlab-ci-cd-bc080cfc6dce) relying on Docker or [that article](https://aarongorka.com/blog/gitlab-monorepo-pipelines/) taking advantage of the `needs:` key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your comment I understand you'd be interested in adopting a *monorepo* configuration.

In this case, for the question

> **Where do I manage/put the docker-compose file?**

you could just put the `docker-compose.yml` file at the root of your GitLab CI project, which would lead to a directory structure like this:

```
monorepo-project/
├── backend/
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── .dockerignore
│   └── src/
├── frontend/
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── .dockerignore
│   └── src/
├── docker-compose.yml
├── .git/
├── .gitignore
└── .gitlab-ci.yml
```

As pointed out in https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/workflows/monorepo.html (the original version of this page, deleted by [this commit](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/commit/b68b6c610afa5707e289ddc0df1e9d7fdbc5919f), is still available at [this URL](https://web.archive.org/web/20201130172957/https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/workflows/monorepo.html)), you can tweak your configuration using the [`changes:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlychanges--exceptchanges) key, so that if just one part of the project changes (e.g., the frontend), then the CI behaves accordingly.

#### Further pointers

For more examples, see e.g. [this article in Medium](https://medium.com/swlh/on-monorepos-and-the-deployment-with-gitlab-ci-cd-bc080cfc6dce) which specifically relies on [Docker](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/), or [that blog article](https://aarongorka.com/blog/gitlab-monorepo-pipelines/) which takes advantage of the [`needs:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs) key.

Finally, the semantics of the GitLab CI YAML conf file is well-documented in https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/ (to be bookmarked!).